# Is there a way to write this negation code more concisely?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some refactoring and the code I'm trying to clean up some code that uses negation if the case is false.

This is the code I have.

if-else

```
if (isTrue) {
  return runAlgorithm();
} else {
  return !(runAlgorithm());
}
```

written more concisely with ternary:

```
isTrue ? runAlgorithm() : !(runAlgorithm())
```

Is there any better way of writing this?

Comment: Do you really want to run the algorithm if it is not true? Or is it enough to pass ?

Comment: note: you left out the return in the ternary example

Comment: Using the xor operator (i.e. `return isTrue ^ !runAlgorithm()`) would get you the same result as your original formulation, assuming that `isTrue` is actually a `boolean` value. I can type this up as an answer if you'd like a full derivation. But I'd probably keep the logic as you have it [or use Hogan's fine answer], assuming that `runAlgorithm()` is all that's happening in each branch, as it is easy to read.

Comment: is that really better motto?  it is much harder to understand for the average programmer.

Comment: @Hogan Yeah strongly agree with you, I had a pang of conscience as soon as I hit submit :-)

Comment: @motto -- it is interesting -- I think this really gets to the heart of good code.  Yours IS faster, maybe, depending on the compiler.  It is possible a good compiler could do this optimization.   Still what is the trade off in readability vs speed.  In modern CPUs we are talking a few milliseconds difference.

Comment: @Hogan Really depends on the context I guess but in Javascript I don't imagine there's even a few milliseconds in it for any modern JIT interpreter. Also marginally easier to set up breakpoints if you have that intermediate stored value. My folly in this instance was answering the question as asked, rather than as intended :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on what you mean by better.  I think the best code makes clear the intent of the code so it is easy to read and understand.  You don't want to sacrifice performance if you can avoid it, but all things being equal you want it to be clear as possible.  I would write this as follows:

```
var result = runAlgorithm();

return isTrue? result : !result;
```

Here we can clearly see what is being done-- you always run the function and then you do something different with the result based on the isTrue variable.